# How do I echo a value (a price) when a bank is selected from a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially, when I select a bank from the list, I want to display a price next to it. For example if I select “Natwest” from the list it will show £20,000 next to it.

This is what I have so far:

```
<label>Banks</label>
<select id="myList">
  <option value="1">Barclays</option>
  <option value="2">HSBC</option>
  <option value="3">LIoyds</option>
  <option value="4">Natwest</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in PHP or Javascript? You have only provided HTML, but no more information as to what you have tried or what is causing problems.

Comment: either is fine.. im not really good with programming! but all i went is a price to be echoed next to a bank when its selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/fttwLxqa/1/)

This can be done using **Javascript**

There is an onchange Event Attribute in HTML which executes a JavaScript when a user changes the selected option of a  element

**HTML**

```
<label>Banks</label>
<select id="myList" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="1">Barclays</option>
    <option value="2">HSBC</option>
    <option value="3">LIoyds</option>
    <option value="4">Natwest</option>
</select>
<label id="demo"></label>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myList").value;
    if(x==1)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "£20,000";
    else if(x==2)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "£30,000";
    else if(x==3)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "£40,000";
    else if(x==4)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "£50,000";
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @TaJP mentioned in his comments, using switch case would be more efficient.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/fttwLxqa/2/) is a fiddle using switch case.

Comment: I think a switch statement would be more efficient.

Comment: Yes...switch can also be used..I just did that with if else...@TaJP

Comment: Brilliant! this looks like what i want :) Thanks Lal

Comment: Great..:) Glad that it helped.. keithyboi.. as @TaJP mentioned in his comment, using a switch case would be more efficient.

Comment: Ah dont confuse me haha. im not very good with programming so i wouldnt even know how to do that either..

Comment: If thats the case, i will update the answer with a fiddle with switch case

Comment: only need one `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` statement ....`DRY` means Do Not Repeat Yourself

Comment: @charlietfl Surely the code can be reduced, but then each case is executed just once. So simply assigning that to a variable mightbe useless.

Comment: @keithyboi What about the updated answer? Did it help you?

Comment: Hey @Lal yeah it did thanks, exactly what i was looking for :) now i just need to style it and im sorted.

Comment: Good going.. :) Happy coding.. :) @keithyboi

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution with jquery/ajax. 
It request a Server-Side-PHP-Script and fetch necessary data (like prices) and display the result next to Select-Field.

**HTML Stuff**

```
<label>Banks</label>
    <select id="myList">
        <option value = "1">Barclays</option>
        <option value = "2">HSBC</option>
        <option value = "3">LIoyds</option>
        <option value = "4">Natwest</option>
    </select>

    <span id="result"></span>

<script>

$( "#myList" ).change(function() {

  // Send the data using post, in PHP you will get $_POST['bankId']
  var posting = $.post('banks.php', { bankId: $(this).val() } );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
   $("#result").empty().append(data);
  });


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Script (banks.php)**

```
<?php 
// file banks.php
$arrBankData = array('20,00 EUR','25,00 EUR','30,00 EUR','35,00 EUR');

if($_POST) {
    if(isset($arrBankData[$_POST['bankId']]))
        echo $arrBankData[$_POST['bankId']];
    else
        echo "Bank ID not found!";
}
?>
```